# Container below slideshow without padding or margin

Tags: css

A full width slideshow with a `position:absolute;`. Now I want the container, where all the content will be below the slideshow, but I can't use `padding-top` / `margin-top` because the height of the slideshow will depend on the screen width.

**HTML5:**

```
<main>
  <ul class="slideshow">
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/SiSnJdh.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Hello Stackoverflow!</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index:300;
  margin-top:-15px;
}
.slideshow li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index:400;
}
.slideshow li:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  z-index:400;
}
.slideshow img {
  display: block;
  z-index:400;
  min-height:180px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.container {
  width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sawnma64/3/

Is it possible to get the container below the slideshow without using a `padding-top` or `margin-top`? I have tried `clear:both;` but it is not working.

Comment: not with that slideshow using `position:absolute` and not giving it a height of some kind.  Why do you need to set it to `absolute`?  Maybe if we can fix that problem it'll fix this one too.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Well, that seem to work. I use a JS extension for the slideshow and the site said it should have a `position: absolute` that's why I used it. Thanks! :)

Comment: well, that's just half of the problem at this point.  Slideshows usually need some kind of positioning, but if you can set it to `relative` it'll avoid this kind of collapsing.  Also, your CSS has a `sideshow` rule that should be `.slideshow`

Comment: Yes, I set it to `relative` and now it is working perfect. I saw it, it was a small typo ;). Could you please give an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is that the slideshow itself is set to `position:absolute`.  This position attribute takes the slideshow out of the document flow resulting in it overlapping and hiding the rest of the content.  Whatever slideshow plugin that is being used appears to need the slideshow to have a non-static position attribute (any position attribute other than `position:static`, which is the default when position is not set).  That's because the individual slides are `position:absolute`, which depends on a non-static parent for its dimensions reference.

For your case, `position:relative` is what you need.  It provides that point of reference or the `position:absolute` children, but it doesn't take the slideshow out of document flow.